# Literature for introducing changes in software development process - not agile introduction

Tags: development-process, process-improvement

I apologize for the lengthy question! The point is that I would like to ask book recommendations for my thesis where it is described how to introduce changes in an existing software development process. For details, please read the lengthy part.

I'm going to write my thesis (MBA) about how my team innovated our software development process by switching from TFVC to git and introducing more fine grained work tracking structure to be able to make more data driven decisions. It is subject of technology management science. What we did is process innovation. The main topic of my thesis is the process how to introduce new procedures, methods in an already existing process. For example: What are the steps you take? What are the parameters of your decision? How POCs can help? Where is the point of no return? Etc.

Due to that the university where I study more manufacturing focused than software development, the literature I got by my teaching material is also rather manufacturing focused. And also expected from the pupil (myself) that he/she should display that by his/her thesis he/she has an understanding about the available literature of the given science. What I have now is [An implementation model for reducing resistance to technological change](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hfm.4530040107/full) written by Mica R. Endsley and published in 1994. It is an excellent start, but as I said it is rather manufacturing focused and written before dot com crisis.

Despite the fact software development and software delivery took its methods (Could I say that its initial steps?) from manufacturing we don't have those restrictions (let's says, they are lightened in various extend) in software development as manufacturing has. For example, in SD you will have a failed build or dropped MVP having little cost, however the same dead end might cost significantly more in manufacturing. My point is, what is described by Endsley is a good start, but the change process in SD shall not be that rigid as it is described. As a consequence, I have to make a fine distinction between manufacturing processes and software development processes and shed on light that introducing change in software development process has similarities to that described by Endsley's and also it has differences too. In order to support the point above, I need literature from software development area about the suggested way of making changes in an already existing process. Beside that the thesis will have a conclusion where my experiences will be shown. Unfortunately, I can't recall any books about this topic because those I read are about introducing kanban, scrum and technology related stuff. Making changes in processes are driven by common sense in my world, but it is not enough in a thesis.

You might say PDCA cycle should be good. It is not applicable here because switching TFVC to git is rather a big bang thing than an iterative enhancement.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Unfortunately, your question is out of scope here. As it is written on [Help Center](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, this site is NOT about recommendations for blogs, books, links, or general terminology.

Answer (score 3):

These are some that I have recently listened to. I have put links to Audiobooks. Play at 1.5-2X speed which will help get through them quicker for your MBA.

Manufacturing, but applicable to Software [The Goal](https://www.audible.co.uk/pd/Business/The-Goal-Audiobook/B00IFGIUX0/ref=a_search_c4_1_2_srTtl?qid=1508311542&sr=1-2)

How a disaster project is turned around by switching to Agile methodolgy [The Phoenix Project](https://www.audible.co.uk/pd/Business/The-Phoenix-Project-Audiobook/B00VB034GK/ref=a_search_c4_1_1_srTtl?qid=1508311700&sr=1-1)

Similar to The Phoenix Project [Rolling Rocks Downhill](https://www.audible.co.uk/pd/Non-fiction/Rolling-Rocks-Downhill-Audiobook/B01DYS9V22/ref=a_search_c4_1_1_srTtl?qid=1508311731&sr=1-1)

Most of the books by Steve McConnell could be useful. [Rapid Development](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rapid-Development-Taming-Software-Schedules/dp/1556159005/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1508311841&sr=8-3&keywords=steve%20mcconnell) is >20 years old now, but I still refer back to it even now. You can pick up secondhand copies from Amazon cheaply if your region has used copies available (for example in the UK for 0.01p + post).

The Phoenix Project and Rolling Rocks may be more applicable to you as they start with a project that is in chaos (late, burned out developers, etc) and basically start adding Agile methology but chopping out requirements/wishes, starting smaller releases, starting testing earlier, things like that.

Good luck with your MBA.

Answer (score 0):

[Commitment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9462410038) by Olav Maassen.

> Via Rose Randall, the main character of this unique graphic business
>   novel, the reader is introduced to the challenges a project manager
>   faces. Rose Randall is the archetypal reluctant project manager.
>   Following a painful project failure years ago, Rose's life is cast
>   into chaos when she is once again thrown into the role against her
>   wishes. Faced with a struggling project, help comes from an unexpected
>   source guiding Rose in the direction of Real Options.